# Can not create jms-queue in wildfly using jboss-cli

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly, jboss-cli, jms-queue

I started wildfly 24 server with standalone-full.xml profile, when i run following command in jboss-cli to create jms-queue i get following error

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] jms-queue --profile=full add --queue-address=foo --entries=["java:/jms/queue/foo"]
WFLYCTL0175: Resource [
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default")
] does not exist; a resource at address [
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default"),
    ("jms-queue" => "foo")
] cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added
```

What am i missing here? Any reference docs to create the jms server, queues?

**Update:**
I tried to create the server using web console first
[image]

And it filed with the required capabilities are not available, any documentation refernece that indicates what are the required capabilities i need to added prior configuring JMS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes don't use the profile parameter which is used in domain mode.

```
jms-queue add --queue-address=foo --entries=["java:/jms/queue/foo"]
```

works properly.

Comment: I have no idea how this is working for you, i just downloaded "wildfly24", and executed the command you given. I get the same error "cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added"  am i missing any other configuraton? what other configuration need prior configuring jms-queue. Please post sample if you have. This will help others too

Comment: you need to start wildfly in full mode: ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml

Comment: I started the wildfly with standalone-full profile, i have mentioned this in my initial question and updated my initial question with web console experience

Answer (score -1):

The issue is i was using wildfly "WildFly Preview EE 9.1 Distribution" the correct verirsion is "Jakarta EE 8 Full & Web Distribution"

[image]